# How to highlight current page using css in asp.net master-child pages

Tags: asp.net, navigation, master-pages

I have the master-child pages in asp.net, i want to highlight the page which is currently active, it can be done easily using id's for various pages and navigation links in css, but here in asp.net master-child page concept, there is no `<body>` for child contents, how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a css style. you could use something like :

```
<a href='Page1.aspx' class="<%=SetCssClass('Page1.aspx')%>"></a>
<a href='Page2.aspx' class="<%=SetCssClass('Page2.aspx')%>"></a>
<a href='Page3.aspx' class="<%=SetCssClass('Page3.aspx')%>"></a>
<a href='Page4.aspx' class="<%=SetCssClass('Page4.aspx')%>"></a>
```

U can now use a  simple function to set the css class to use